# How to access PowerShell host from C#

Tags: c#, powershell, reflection

In a PowerShell profile, one can identify the PowerShell host in order to do appropriate setup for that host's environment. For example:

```
if ($host.Name -eq 'ConsoleHost')
{
    Import-Module PSReadline
    # differentiate verbose from warnings!
    $privData = (Get-Host).PrivateData
    $privData.VerboseForegroundColor = "cyan"
}
elseif ($host.Name -like '*ISE Host')
{
    Start-Steroids
    Import-Module PsIseProjectExplorer
}
```

I would like to be able to do the equivalent identification from a C# context primarily because PowerShell ISE does not support `Console.ReadLine` so I want to know if it is safe to use it in the current PS host's environment.

I first explored trying to get the output of the `Get-Host` cmdlet from within C# (per [Invoking a cmdlet within a cmdlet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714876(v=vs.85).aspx)). After I located the Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Utility assembly (under C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\WindowsPowerShell\3.0) I could compile this but it yielded null...

```
var cmd = new Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetHostCommand();
var myHost = cmd.Invoke();
```

...while this would not compile due to the `InternalHost` class being (ironically!) internal:

```
var cmd = new Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetHostCommand();
var myHost = cmd.Invoke<System.Management.Automation.Internal.Host.InternalHost>();
```

Next, I then modified my cmdlet to inherit from `PSCmdlet` rather than `Cmdlet` (to allow access to the `SessionState`), so I could then access the PS host object like this:

```
var psVarObject = SessionState.PSVariable.GetValue("Host");
```

Of course, that returns a pure `Object`, which I then needed to cast to... oh, wait... it's still internal!... so this would not compile:

```
string psHost = ((System.Management.Automation.Internal.Host.InternalHost)psVarObject).Name;
```

Leaving me no alternative but to use reflection on a foreign assembly (*horrors!*):

```
string psHost = (string)psVarObject.GetType().GetProperty("Name").GetValue(psVarObject, null);
```

That works, but is less than ideal, because reflecting upon any 3rd-party assembly is a fragile thing to do.

Any alternative ideas on either (a) identifying the host or, (b) backing up a bit, being able to use the host's own Read-Host cmdlet to get a typed input from a user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use [Host](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.management.automation.pscmdlet.host.aspx) property from PSCmdlet class. And if you want to do `Read-Host`:

```
Host.UI.ReadLine()
```

Comment: Bravo! Amazing what one can do when one knows the right bits!

Answer (score 0):

When getting

```
var psVarObject = SessionState.PSVariable.GetValue("Host");
```

You can cast it to `System.Management.Automation.Host.PSHost` instead of `InternalHost`